# R Shiny: "All" Radio Button

Tags: r, shiny

I successfully launched the following code that outputs two options for RadioButtons: "No" and "Yes." However, I want to add a third radio button, call it "All," that shows values of "No" and "Yes" together in one output.

How do I go about doing this?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

bcl <- read.csv("testd10Apr2017V4.csv", sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Attrition VS Age"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
#      sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", 0, 100, c(25, 40), pre = "$"),
      radioButtons("typeInput", "Type",
                   choices = c("No", "Yes", "All"),
                   selected = "Yes", inline = TRUE, width = "200px"),
      hr(),
      helpText("Attrition no means there is no attrition")
#     selectInput("countryInput", "Country",
#                 choices = c("CANADA", "FRANCE", "ITALY"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot")
#      br(), br(),
#      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      bcl %>%
      filter(#Price >= input$priceInput[1],
             #Price <= input$priceInput[2],
             Type == input$typeInput
#             Country == input$countryInput
      )
    g <- ggplot(filtered, aes(Age)) +
      geom_histogram(color = "white", fill = "maroon")
    g + ylim(0,30) + xlim(0,60)
    g
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run the code since I didn't have the datafile, but something like this should work for you.
Inside the server function, you can add something like below:

```
if (input$typeInput == "All"){
    filtered <- bcl
} else {
    filtered <- bcl %>% 
      filter(Type == input$typeInput)
}
```